# Estoy usando reactjs, alguien me puede ayudar a que cuando haga clic en un botón este se quede permanentemente de otro color?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy usando reactjs para una aplicación web, tengo duda de saber como hacer para que cuando le de clic en un botón este se quede se un solo color,a menos que le de clic otra vez en este o en algún otro.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esos son los botenes, los tengo en un componente

```javascript
import React from 'react';
import './SelecButton.css';


function SelectButton({Text}){
    return(
        <div className="SelectButton-container">
            <button className="SelectButton-style">{Text} </button>
        </div>
    )
}


export default SelectButton;
```

Este es el código del componente

Comment: Existen varias soluciones, como por ejemplo: A. pasarle al componente SelectButton un parámetro extra con la clase o el estilo a usar o B. usar el estado del componente para saber cuándo se ha pulsado.